# wxMaxima: "*" wrong number of arguments

Tags: tex, maxima, infix-notation, wxmaxima

I used `texput` to redefine the `tex1` output for `*`:

```
texput("*", "", infix);
```

but this causes an error when there are more than two terms:

```
tex1(a*b); 
   > ab
tex1(a*b*c);
   > "*": wrong number of arguments.
```

Any idea why this is happening or how I might work around it?

Comment: Try `texput("*", "<whatever>", nary)` instead -- `nary` means n-ary (i.e., multiple, indefinite number of arguments).